# PHP curl not sending post params

Tags: php, curl, http-post

I have an online form to submit data as http post.
If no data is send as post , it will return the following error message

> We are sorry, the form that you have submitted is invalid or no longer exists.

I am using the following code to send http post data using curl.But I am always getting the error message as output.
How to resolve this issue.Did I miss anything.I printed the curl request, and the post parameters are not sent.How can I fix this?
My code is given below

```html
function curlUsingPost($url, $data)
{
  $content_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

    if(empty($url) OR empty($data))
    {
        return 'Error: invalid Url or Data';
    }

    
    //url-ify the data for the POST
    $fields_string = '';
    foreach($data as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    $fields_string = http_build_query($data).'\n';
    echo $fields_string;


    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
 //   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Accept: ' . $content_type]);
 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array($content_type));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Expect:' ) );
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10); # timeout after 10 seconds, you can increase it
   //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  # Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
   curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)"); # Some server may refuse your request if you dont pass user agent

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
   
   
   $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    
   print_r($info );
    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);



    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}


$url = 'office.promptip.com:8443/his1.max/Services/Webform.aspx?request=submitwebform&amp;token=202D36560E444E466658461615120F75411B09634C696C6F79454E795E7C7A5154505645414F456C584C17101B443D431D0B654D66686D7C454E795E2D7E5152565341404145625E4213141E4273421E5E66486B666F2A464B7A5B79785F54520645444F15635C454516134422421A0D664A3D68687C454E79587F7D5F52575714424043635E1611181D16704D1D0E654F69696F2A474A7A0A78785807525E45414E406350424016134422421A0D374C6F686C7C44482F59787D5E530150104218426D584316181A4177411B0F';
//echo $url;
$data = [
'C0IFirstName' => 'John Doe',
'C1ILastName' => 'Doe John',
'C2IPosition' =>'Father-Guardian',
'U3I80'=>'8129020464',
'U4I150'=>'johndoe@johndoe.com',
'U5I79'=>'This is the message buddy',
'U6I102' => 'Ann',
'U7I105' =>'Doe',
'U8I52' =>'FS1',
'C9IClientId'=> rand ( 0,100000 ),
'U10I21'=>'Website-Enquiry Form'

];

echo curlUsingPost($url,$data);
```

Comment: `curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Expect:' ) );` is wrong - the handle should be $ch in this case

Comment: ya I removed Expect: .Still it is not working.(Expect was added because of suggestion from an online link)

Comment: You can use implode function to concatenate the postfields instead of putting '&' at end, as this will end up in a extra '&' at last.

Comment: you can increase the timeout time.

Comment: I'm unable to see the particular form that you are trying to submit on the url given - is it beyond the login page?

Comment: No..There is no form...The form is submitted programatically The error message will be retunred, if no fields are posted.My issue is that HTTP POST fields are not sending along with CURY request .(See the  curl_getinfo($ch); output).The url is the action URL of form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Add this to your curl request:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

And replace `&amp;` with `&` in URL you're requesting:

```
$url = 'office.promptip.com:8443/his1.max/Services/Webform.aspx?request=submitwebform&token=202D36560E444E466658461615120F75411B09634C696C6F79454E795E7C7A5154505645414F456C584C17101B443D431D0B654D66686D7C454E795E2D7E5152565341404145625E4213141E4273421E5E66486B666F2A464B7A5B79785F54520645444F15635C454516134422421A0D664A3D68687C454E79587F7D5F52575714424043635E1611181D16704D1D0E654F69696F2A474A7A0A78785807525E45414E406350424016134422421A0D374C6F686C7C44482F59787D5E530150104218426D584316181A4177411B0F';
```

### Explenation

At first, you're requesting wrong URL, which was probably copied from some HTML documentation. Normally a `&amp;` entity would be replaced by `&` char by HTML interpreter, but this does not work with curl and you have to replace the entity manually.

Also the server returns

> We are sorry, the form that you have submitted is invalid or no
>   longer exists.

for each end every request in response body. But for successfull request it also provides a `Location` header. Normally browser would follow this location, make a second request and display success message. You have to tell cURL to do exactly the same with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true)`.

Comment: Hi pamelus.Thank you for the response.Let me try this.Actually I was travelling.That's why I couln't respond immedietely

Comment: Hi Pamelus.One more issue..It is working in my local mamp.But on server, it is returning nothing

Comment: What does the `curl_error($ch)` say? Remember to put `curl_error` after `curl_exec`.

Comment: It says couldn't connect